# how to fix: Skype resets settings on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, skype

Recently every time I start Skype and login it goes via initial configuration sequences, and every time i need to turn off notifications "when user goes online".

That has been for a while and many Skype version has been upgraded.
I guess if I disable updates, then I will not need to confgigure Skype every time it launches.